How to add Spine animation to Phaser3 game
Im trying to add an animation from Spine to my game using 3 spine files from phaser example
,
but i don't know how it work. First i load spine pack in preload() :
 this.load.setPath('assets/images/'); 
 this.load.spine('spineboy', 'spineboy-ess.json', 'spineboy.atlas');

In my create(), I'm trying to add the animation to my scene, like in the phaser example link :
this.spineBoy = this.add.spine(2400, 900, 'spineboy.spineboy', 'idle', true);

When i try to run, my console show this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'skeletonData')

Did i do something wrong? How can i add my spine into my game?

Check which Phaser and which spine-plugin Version you are using. If your Versions match the ones of the example it should work.

Im using Phaser 3.80.1 and SpinePluginDebug4.1 , spine package is from Phaser example repo on Github

Are the json and atlas files in the folder /assets/images ? Are there any other Errors in the console, like "404 (Not Found)" or so?

no, there is not any other error.

when i try to use another spine package, this error appear
Error: ;Unknown texture filter true

This error has to do with the plugin version / type. Using the Phaser plugin javascript file from the demo, the solution should be as mentioned in my answer.

I just wanted to ask is this issue solved? If so and my answer helped, please consider accepting my anwser with the green checkmark, by the voting arrows. Thanks in Advance

Well the issue has probably todo with the fact, that you renamed the file atlas1.png to spineboy.png without changing the file name in the first line of the atlas1.atlas file.
(First few lines of the atlas file)
      atlas1.png
      size:1024,1024
      filter:Linear,Linear
      ...

Would have to be
      spineboy.png
      size:1024,1024
      filter:Linear,Linear
      ...

if you change the first line to spineboy.png, it should work.
